# Parameter of SelectOneMethod listener null without RequestScoped

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, primefaces

I am having trouble with a NullpointerException in a listenerMethod from a SelectOneMenu. It does only work in @RequestScoped, not with @View/SessionScoped. The Nullpointer is being thrown when trying to use the parameter of the listenerMethod of a SelectOneMenu. The parameter is also the value from the selectOneMenue.

Here are the code snippets

.xhtml snippet

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="facility" value="#{visualization.facility}" converter="#{facilityConverterBean}" style="width:150px">
   <p:ajax process="@this" partialSubmit="true" listener="#{visualization.onFacilityChange()}" update="componentt" />
   <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select Facility" noSelectionOption="true" />
   <f:selectItems value="#{visualization.facilities}" var="facility" itemLabel="#{facility.name}" itemValue="#{facility}" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

ViewManager.java

```
@ViewScoped
@Named("visualization")
public class VisualizationViewManager implements Serializable{

    @Inject
    private ClientService clientService;
    @Inject
    private FacilityService facilityService;
    @Inject
    private ComponentService componentService;
    @Inject
    private BhkwService bhkwService;

    private Facility facility;
    private List<Facility> facilities;

    private Bhkw component;
    private List<Bhkw> components;

    private Date dateFrom;
    private Date dateTo;

    private int recordCount = 100;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        facilities = clientService.getFacilitiesByClient();
    }

    public void onFacilityChange(){
        //HERE: facility is null at this point
        // even though it should be set by the selectOneMenue             
        components = facilityService.getComponentsByFacility(facility);

    }
```

Can anyone tell me why this is happening? it works perfectly fine with @RequestScoped.

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: Is the ViewScoped-import from the right package? The one with "view" in it

Comment: Thanks for your comment. A man has found an answer for his problem. A man had a "@named" Annotation with "@ViewScoped" together, which couldn't work, a man changed the named Annotation to "@ManagedBean(name="bla") which made it work. Thank you for your help though. Valar morghulis.